# Azure Kubernetes Service Scaling and HPA

Tags: azure, prometheus, azure-aks, hpa

Is there a way that "request per second" based scaling can be enabled on Azure Kubernetes Service?

HPA in AKS does allow horizontal pod scaling based on CPU and Memory constraints but there is no straightforward way to do it for - requests per second.
Is there a way to use advanced metrics in the metrics server bundled by AKS?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Azure Application Gateway as your Ingress Controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-overview), you can use its metrics for Horizontal Autoscaler. You can find documentation regarding the use case [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-autoscale-pods). Note that this feature seems to still be in beta.